# .NET core CLI -> run ERROR

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-cli

I have a little bit of problem with dotnet core CLI.

When I am in a project directory and type:

```
dotnet restore
dotnet publish
```

It creates published version of my code. And it says that my project is in `**PROJECT NAME** -> /Users/**NAME**/hwapp/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/hwapp.dll`.

After typing `dotnet run` it runs my code but when I step to that directory with my dll file compiled and run that dll with dotnet run command i get the following error.

[image: ERROR]

Can some please explain me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dotnet run` is a development tool meant to run msbuild projects (e.g. `csproj`), not execute built applications.

Use `dotnet hwapp.dll` to run a built application.